# How to initialize persisted sessions into passport / session-file-store at startup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, passport.js

This express application uses passport to authenticate with azure. When a user authenticates, the user data is saved to an in-memory store, which then gets written to a session store.

When the express application re-starts, it loads the previously saved user data from the session store. However, passport does not recognize previously authenticated users and it requires them to re-authenticate. This is a problem, because the app is still in development and requires frequent re-starts.

**I want the application to recognize previously authenticated users after the application restarts.**

---

**UPDATE:** After some more research, I see the sessions are managed by the `express-session` package. I have added the `session-file-store` package to the code and configured it to save sessions. The sessions still do not persist.

---

This application began from this [ms graph tutorial](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/tree/main/demo/graph-tutorial). It serializes and deserializes user data into a memory store and I added code to persist the data. But there is a disconnect between the stored user data and the session key stored in the browser.

The application stores the users by using their `oid` as the key, like this:

```
{
    "1aa31bba-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx": {
        "profile": {
            "sub": "_v3k8L5PkIREMis1in9IF3SucjEQqxRxThsoK35rBZQ",
            "oid": "1aa31bba-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, the browser has a session cookie that is not the oid:

```
"connect.sid":"s:cd957624-72ba-4552-893d-8fd59bbce31e.Gt87eHx0WjkKXOKeq6oDvsw35BZZ+6ZQ6p0c3dwjRTE"
```

The cookie `connect.sid` is the only cookie stored in the browser. The cookie's value changes every time the user re-authenticates. This cookie does not get written to either the user file or the sessions file. This is the disconnect that I do not know how to resolve.

**What is the proper way to initialize `session-file-store` at startup with previous sessions?**

Here is application's passport code.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);  // added to test FileStore

require('dotenv').config();

var users = {};
var userStore = require('userStore');
users = userStore.load();

// Passport calls serializeUser and deserializeUser to manage users
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    // Use the OID property of the user as a key
    users[user.profile.oid] = user;
    userStore.save(users);
    done(null, user.profile.oid);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done(null, users[id]);
});

const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create({
    client: {
        id: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
        secret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD
    },
    auth: {
        tokenHost: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY,
        authorizePath: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT,
        tokenPath: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    }
});

async function signInComplete(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
    if (!profile.oid) {
        return done(new Error("No OID found in user profile."));
    }
    try {
        const user = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);
        if (user) {
            // Add properties to profile
            profile['email'] = user.mail ? user.mail : user.userPrincipalName;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
    // Create a simple-oauth2 token from raw tokens
    let oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(params);
    // Save the profile and tokens in user storage
    users[profile.oid] = { profile, oauthToken };
    return done(null, users[profile.oid]);
}

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(
    {
        identityMetadata: `${process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY}${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
        clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
        responseType: 'code id_token',
        responseMode: 'form_post',
        redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
        allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
        clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
        validateIssuer: false,
        passReqToCallback: false,
        scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(' ')
    },
    signInComplete
));

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
    store: new FileStore({}), // added to test FileStore
    genid: uuid,
    resave: true, // false,  // changed to test FileStore
    saveUninitialized: true, // false,  // changed to test FileStore
    unset: 'destroy'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Share the npm link to this package require('sessionStore'), post which I can help you with the changes.

Comment: The sessionStore is internal. It only has `load` and `save` functions, with no connection to passport or express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause turned out to be that the `user.oauthtoken` object is an instance of class `AuthToken`. When the user is serialized to storage, the json only records the object properties (because json). So when the user is de-serialized after the app restarts, `user.oauthtoken` is only an `Object` and not an `AuthToken`.

The solution was simple. I changed the de-serialize function from this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done(null, users[id]);
});
```

to this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    let user = users[id];
    if( user.oauthToken.constructor.name !== "AccessToken" ) {
        user.oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(user.oauthToken.token);
    }
    done(null, user);
});
```

With this simple change, the rest of the app is able to call the access token's methods and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Changes below should help, since i'm not sure about the "sessionStore", I made it in-memory, once you restart application, users list will erase and signup again.

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
require('dotenv').config();

// Ideally this needs to be replaced with DB
var users = [];

// This is not required if DB is present
let getUser = (id) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
        if (users[index].id === id) {
            return users[index];
            break;
        }
    }
};

// This is not required if DB is present
let checkIfUserExists = (id) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
        if (users[index].id === id) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    // This is not required if DB is present, just get the user from DB
    let user = getUser(id);

    done(null, user);
});

const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create({
    client: {
        id: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
        secret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD
    },
    auth: {
        tokenHost: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY,
        authorizePath: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT,
        tokenPath: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    }
});

function signInComplete(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
    // Encapsulating the logic in nexttick function helps manage event loop
    process.nextTick(async () => {
        if (profile.oid) {
            if (checkIfUserExists(profile.oid)) {
                // getUser and return user, if DB this part will change
                let user = getUser(profile.oid);
                let userDetails = {};
                try {
                    userDetails = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);
                } catch (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }
                user.userDetails = userDetails;
                user.oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(params);
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // Create a new user and return user, will change when db comes to place
                let userDetails = {};
                try {
                    userDetails = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);
                } catch (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }
                // User structure have retained my best based on the current code
                let newUser = {
                    id: profile.oid,
                    userDetails: userDetails, 
                    profile: profile,
                    oauthToken: oauth2.accessToken.create(params)
                };
                users.push(newUser);
                return done(null, newUser)
            }
        } else {
            return done(new Error("No OID found in user profile."));    
        }
    });
}

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(
    {
        identityMetadata: `${process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY}${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
        clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
        responseType: 'code id_token',
        responseMode: 'form_post',
        redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
        allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
        clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
        validateIssuer: false,
        passReqToCallback: false,
        scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(' ')
    },
    signInComplete
));

// See the passport documentation for this part
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
    genid: uuid,
    resave: false, // Change to true once you have a store
    saveUninitialized: false // Change to true once you have a store
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

For reference [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/),

Comment: I already have a solution that forces users to re-authenticate when the application restarts.